Google Chrome only runs under sudo
Just installed Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04. After installing Google Chrome, whenever I try to open it, a crash process is started in system monitor, but there's no terminal output. Not even in debug mode.
After using sudo and checking the debug log, I get this:
[7573:7573:0825/010259.015760:WARNING:chrome_main_delegate.cc(742)] This is Chrome version 128.0.6613.84 (not a warning)
[7641:7641:0825/010319.579959:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(430)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[7643:7643:0825/010334.353133:INFO:child_thread_impl.cc(971)] ChildThreadImpl::EnsureConnected()

Chrome launches under sudo, but not from the desktop launcher.
Tried:

[19141:19141:0425/011526.129520:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374) InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process

--no-sandbox



Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04 and the latest Google Chrome release.

Everything fixed itself after installing all updates.
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

